# m1 = 001, m2=101 How can I calculate Bitwise XOR between m1 and m2?

Tags: xor, bitwise-xor

m1 = 001, m2=101 How can I calculate Bitwise XOR between m1 and m2?

Could you check if my solution is correct or not? please tell me your opinions.

m1 = 001 => in 8bit(8byte?) anyway, I can express it 0000 0001

m2 = 101 => same way as m1, I can express it 0000 0101

0000 0001
0000 0101

Same part will be 0,
Different part will be 1

so, the answer is

100(0000 0100)

Comment: Yes 0^0 = 0, 0^1 = 1, 1^0 = 1, 1^1 = 0. Or short 0011^0101 = 0110

Comment: @JoopEggen Thank you. my solution is correct, right? and 8 bit? 8 byte which one is correct?

Comment: Everything fine, even the understanding that only different bits yield a 1. And of course "bitwise" means every bit at position _i_ applied to the other bit at position _i_.

Comment: Should the terms _bit_ and _byte_ be unclear. A _byte_  is composed of 8 bits, and every _bit_ is a _binary digit_, 0 or 1. _Byte_ is also associated with _bite_, a mouth taken piece of food. And so there is also a _nibble_ of 4 bits.